# How to execute twitter.Api.PostUpdate in loop?

Tags: python, twitter, praw

This code executes with error:

```
  # some constants and auth before, looks not important
  topPosts = reddit.get_subreddit('funny').get_top(limit=3)
  for post in topPosts:
        twitter.PostUpdate(status = post.title, media = post.url)
```

Console log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    twitter.PostUpdate(status = post.title, media = post.url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 990, in PostUpdate
    media_additional_owners)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 1132, in UploadMediaChunked
    boundary = bytes("--{0}".format(uuid4()), 'utf-8')
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

If I do just `post.label` in loop it works perfectly.

If I execute only one (w/o loop) `PostUpdate` it works perfectly.

I think it's happening because `PostUpdate` is asynchronous, but can't figure out how to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `python-twitter` library and it's fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/pull/347/files#diff-ca47863eef03007ed84692b07b74eda6L1132). The problem is that `bytes` in python2 equals to `str` and accepts only one argument while in python3 `bytes` requires encoding as a second argument.